# How to pass complex object in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, testng-dataprovider

Our team is moving from clean testng to testng+cucumber. While trying to create a feature for a simple test where an immutable object is sent to service with various data each run(dataprovider in the testng world) I found myself in need of a step with at max 11 fields. Which is kinda a lot - it's a not good practice.

There is any chance cucumber has the possibility to get complex objects from scenario outline?
I was trying to find some docs on my problem but nothing popped up. Maybe I was looking in wrong place or googling with a wrong query.

Ex.

```
@Test(
    dataProvider = "data"
)
public void sendRequestTest(
    SomeComplexRequest request
) {
    //Given

    some test data prep

    //When
    Responce resp = sendRequestToService(request);

    //Then
    assertEquals(resp, expectedResp);
}

@Builder
class SomeComplexRequest{
dataType Field1;
dataType Field2;
dataType Field3;
...
dataType FieldN;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is possible to use example values in a data table:

```
Feature: Basic Arithmetic

  Background: A Calculator
    Given a calculator I just turned on

  Scenario Outline: Many additions
    Given the previous entries:
      | first | second | operation |
      | <x>   | <y>    | <op1>     |
      | <q>   | <r>    | <op2>     |
    When I press +
    And I add <a> and <b>
    And I press +
    Then the result is <c>

    Examples: Single digits
      | x | y | op1 | q | r | op2 | a | b | c |
      | 1 | 1 | +   | 2 | 1 | +   | 1 | 2 | 8 |
      | 0 | 1 | +   | 1 | 2 | +   | 2 | 3 | 9 |
```

And while it is possible to convert this data table to an object in your step definition

```
    @Given("the previous entries:")
    public void thePreviousEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
        for (Entry entry : entries) {
            calc.push(entry.first);
            calc.push(entry.second);
            calc.push(entry.operation);
        }
    }
```

by using a table converter to turn the table into a list of entries:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/java#transformers

```
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @DefaultParameterTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
    public Object transformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, objectMapper.constructType(toValueType));
    }
```

You might not be using Cucumber in the most beneficial way. With 11 parameters you might in fact not even be using your current unit tests in the most beneficial way.

Consider:

1. Eliminating all incidental detail from your tests.
2. Using the proto type pattern. This way you only have to describe the changes made to a prototype request
3. Rethinking your test strategy and restructure your test strategy in such a way that you cucumber tests can focus on the high level behavior while pushing down the details into smaller unit tests.